# Will Wayland finally make it as system composer in 13.04?

Tags: wayland, 13.04

Ubuntu has been talking about moving to Wayland for around 2 years. They even had some actual attempt to make it system composer for 12.10. It failed as Wayland wasn't ready.

But now wayland folks released a stable release and they'll keep backward compatibility from that point.

I'm really hoping to see Wayland making its way in the base install of Ubuntu 13.04. What are the chances of this happening?

Answer (score 3):

> The general X.Org discussion during the Ubuntu Developer Summit was held today to discuss X.Org/Wayland expectations for the Ubuntu 13.04 release.

...

> The Ubuntu 13.04 repository should also pull in the latest Wayland release, which will either be Wayland 1.0 or likely some 1.0.x point release. However, not talked about this week at the Copenhagen UDS was using Wayland as an Ubuntu System Compositor -- something originally targeted for Ubuntu 12.10. I still see it as unlikely that Wayland will play any significant role in Ubuntu 13.04. Wayland/Weston will continue to be packaged and likely serve for experimenting with the new display technology and maybe some primitive desktop application support (assuming they build out GTK and Qt5 with the Wayland back-end enabled), but I will be very surprised if they push it into any default installation for the Raring Ringtail.

[Posted by Michael Larabel on November 01, 2012 on Phoronix.com](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIxOTc)